# Batch for loop using wmic

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, wmic

The output of the below

```
wmic logicaldisk get providername /value
```

using cmd (with limited user rights) on the computer I'm using is:

```
ProviderName=


ProviderName=


ProviderName=\\xxx-SN-NA01\Users2\N\ni


ProviderName=\\xxx-sn-na01\Software_Ca


ProviderName=\\xxx-sn-na01\TSO
```

I'm tring to get to the following stored in a variable named %drives_paths_wmic%:

```
\\xxx-SN-NA01\Users2\N\ni \\xxx-sn-na01\Software_Ca \\xxx-sn-na01\TSO
```

Then for the content of this to be transferred into the variable %file%.

The batch code I currently have is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic logicaldisk get providername /value') do (
  echo %%A >> %drive_paths_Wmic%
)
echo %drive_paths_Wmic%
echo %drive_paths_Wmic% >> %file%
```

Edit: the problem is that nothing gets stored in the %drive_paths_Wmic% variable.

Since the batch file would need to be run on Windows 7 and XP computers, I can't use PowerShell.
Please advise changes to the batch code in order to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify a problem. However:

'1'.  `delims==` syntax

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic logicaldisk get providername /value') do @echo %%A
```

Is the output from above command right? I dare say not, because

'2'. all output from wmic is Unicode. To convert to ASCII try next code snippet:

```
wmic logicaldisk get providername /value >somename.txt
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('type somename.txt') do @echo %%A
```

'3'. Result to variable:

```
set "file=" 
rem variable initialized now
rem ... some code ...
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('type somename.txt') do set file=!file! %%A
rem ... some code ...
echo !file!
echo %file%
```

or may be `set "file=!file! %%A"` as well

Complete batch:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "drive_paths_Wmic=" 
rem variable initialized now
rem ... some code ...
wmic logicaldisk get providername /value >somename.txt
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('type somename.txt') do (
  set drive_paths_Wmic=!drive_paths_Wmic! %%A
  @rem ... some code ...
  )
echo !drive_paths_Wmic!
echo %drive_paths_Wmic%
Endlocal
goto :eof
```

Output (on my computer):

```
C:\bat>fivmic
 \\pc1870a\ttemp \\PC1870A\Install
 \\pc1870a\ttemp \\PC1870A\Install
```

Output (part with `echo ON`)

```
C:\bat>fivmic
C:\bat>wmic logicaldisk get providername /value  1>somename.txt
C:\bat>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %A in ('type somename.txt') do set drive_paths_Wmic=!drive_paths_Wmic! %A
C:\bat>set drive_paths_Wmic=!drive_paths_Wmic! \\pc1870a\ttemp
C:\bat>set drive_paths_Wmic=!drive_paths_Wmic! \\PC1870A\Install
C:\bat>rem ... some code ...
C:\bat>echo !drive_paths_Wmic!
 \\pc1870a\ttemp \\PC1870A\Install
C:\bat>echo  \\pc1870a\ttemp \\PC1870A\Install
 \\pc1870a\ttemp \\PC1870A\Install
```

And if `%file%` variable contains valid filename, then you could redirect echo to that file, e.g. `echo bubu >> anyname.txt` appends text *bubu*  (on a new line) to file `anyname.txt`. In your script:

```
set file="anyname.txt"
echo %drive_paths_Wmic% >> %file%
```

Comment: Ok I've edited the question to include the problem. I'll try the suggestions and let you know the outcome.

Comment: I've now used your code in "complete batch". The "somename.txt" file gets created, and is populated, however the program exits when try to run the for /f ... loop line. How should this be changed?

Comment: Try `set ECHO ON`. An error message? Which last ECHOed line?

Comment: with `@echo on` the last line echoed is: `wmic logicaldisk get providername /value >somename.txt` no error message in cmd window.

Comment: Update your question and paste crucial code snippet there, please

Comment: This is now resolved - I forgot to include /f switch in `for` loop. Thanks for your help!